# Springboot / MyBatis batch insert not rolling back on error (or even when forced)

Tags: spring-mybatis

I'm trying to get Transactions to work in SpringBoot + MyBatis, but it doesn't rollback no matter what I try. I already added `@Transactional` to the method too. What am I missing?
Am I doing it wrong? Does `flushStatements()` and `clearCache()` commit? The documentation for `SqlSession.commit()` says "flushStatements and commit" so it seems that it shouldn't.

```java
try (SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionTemplate.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH)) {
    MyMapper1 mapper1 = sqlSession.getMapper(MyMapper1.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < results1.size(); i++) {
        mapper1.insert(results1.get(i));
        if ((i != 0 && i % BATCH_SIZE == 0) || i == results1.size()- 1) {
            sqlSession.flushStatements();
            sqlSession.clearCache();
        }
    }

    sqlSession.rollback(true); // didn't work
    int forceError = 100 / 0; // so I tried this, also didn't work

    MyMapper2 mapper2 = sqlSession.getMapper(MyMapper2.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < results2.size(); i++) {
        count = count + mapper2.insert(results2.get(i));
        if ((i != 0 && i % BATCH_SIZE == 0) || i == results2.size()- 1) {
            sqlSession.flushStatements();
            sqlSession.clearCache();
        }
    }
}
```

My Main application:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    MyService service;
}
```

and the service class:

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
    public void doStuff() {
        insert();
    }

    @Transactional
    private void insert() {
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you've added `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation on SpringBootApplication class or any of `@Configuration` classes.

**UPDATE (as additional code was provided ):**

This should work

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
    
    @Transactional // assuming this method is invoked from external code
    public void doStuff() {
        insert();
    }

    private void insert() { ... }
}
```

if called from another class where `MyService` is injected (`@Autowired`).

`@Transactional` is useless when placed on non-public methods, transaction wrapping even won't occur. Spring's call needs to go through the proxy in order to make it working. So the method will need to be called from another bean.

Navigate here for more details on Spring proxies

https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-transaction-management-transactional-in-depth

https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring

Comment: Yes I have done that. '@EnableTransactionManagement' right after '@SpringBootApplication', then '@Autowired' my service class, and I have '@Transactional' for my insert method

Comment: @sikidhart then show how do you invoke `@Transactional` method. You should remember that it won't work if you call it within same class. It works only when transactional method is invoked from external code

Comment: [You should remember that it won't work if you call it within same class] -> I didn't know this. I edited my original question to show how I called it

Comment: I moved the '@Transactional' but it still wouldn't roll back. It works when I used '@Autowired' for MyMapper.
It doesn't work when I get the mapper from sqlSessionTemplate.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH). sqlSessionTemplate was '@Autowired' too...